# Get the Tables 1st row number

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet that contains several tables. I am using `Match`to find some entries in each table, but the thing is that the rownumber returned is with respect to the table, but not the whole worksheet. How can I get it with respect to the sheet?

[image]

Currently, I am just adding manually the number of rows above `=MATCH(value;array;0)+23` (w.r.t to the image above. , but when there are some records entered in the tables above the used one, then everything crashes.

Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You can start your array range at row 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ROW(TABLENAME)` will give you the first row of the data so:

```
=ROW(Table1)-1
```

or

```
=ROW(Table1[#Headers])
```

Will give the first row of the actual table, where `Table1` is the name of the structured table:

[image]

[image]